# "this" keyword in nodejs does'nt get update when you export new object

Tags: node.js

i have this code in nodejs (commonjs) v14.16.1

```
module.exports.varOne = 'one'

module.exports = {varTwo: 'two', ...module.exports}

console.log('module', module);
console.log(this, this === module.exports);
```

and this is the results after running it

```
module Module {
  id: '.',
  path: '...',
  exports: { varTwo: 'two', varOne: 'one' },
  parent: null,
  filename: '...',
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths: [...]
}
{ varOne: 'one' } false
```

I don't understand why "this" here doesn't change to the new exports? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, the value of `this` doesn't change within a given code context like this.  That's how the language itself works.

You replaced the given `exports` object with a different object.  Nothing in the language will cause that assignment to change the value of `this`.  The value of `this` still points at the original `exports` object.

Fortunately, this isn't a problem in nodejs as you have multiple work-arounds.  You can either not replace the `exports` object (just assign values to the existing one) or you can use `module.exports` to refer to the new object instead of `this`.

FYI, you will notice the same thing with the `exports` variable.  It will still point at the original exports object too.

Comment: please, how can you use `module.exports` to refer to the new object?

Comment: @HouiderWalid - `console.log(module.exports)` or in your example to access one property in the new object `console.log(module.exports.varTwo)`.